# What is $26^{32}\bmod 12$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

What is the correct answer to this expression:

$26^{32}  \pmod  {12}$

When I tried in Wolfram Alpha the answer is $4$, this is also my answer using Fermat's little theorem, but in a calculator the answer is different, $0.$

Comment: How can it be $0$? $3$ does not divide $26$, so $12 (= 3 \times 4)$ can't divide $26^{32}$

Comment: So the answer 4 is correct?

Comment: yes the answer $4$ is correct

Comment: I would suggest that, depending on exactly how you did this on a calculator, at some stage the calculator encountered a very large exponent and truncated the result, throwing off the rest of the calculation.

Comment: Alpha failing on such a "basic" computation is more than unlikely. Even the Windows calculator returns $4$ ! (by chance ?)

Comment: This is not a <s>discussion</s> question on why calculators use fixed-precision floating-point arithmetic... if you use Fermat's little theorem and get the right answer then it's right.

Comment: Generic thread is not a dupe since it doesn't yet handle idemptotent exploits as here, so I am (temporarily) reopening.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, note that $26 \equiv 2 \pmod {12}$, so $26^{32} \equiv 2^{32} \pmod {12}$.

Next, note that $2^4 \equiv 16 \equiv 4 \pmod {12}$, so $2^{32} \equiv \left(2^4\right)^8 \equiv 4 ^8 \pmod {12}$, and $4^2 \equiv 4 \pmod {12}$.

Finally, $4^8 \equiv \left(4^2\right)^4 \equiv 4^4 \equiv \left(4^2\right)^2 \equiv 4^2 \equiv 4 \pmod {12}$.

Then we get the result.

There are slicker solutions with just a few results from elementary number theory, but this is a very basic method which should be easy enough to follow.

Answer (score 5):

$\smash[b]{\text{Note that }\  {\color{#0a0}{26}^{\large 32}\!\bmod 12 
= \color{#0a0}2^{\large 32}\!\bmod{12}}
\,=\, 2^{\large 2}({\overbrace{\color{#c00}2^{\large 30}\!\bmod 3}^{\!\!\!\!\large (\color{#c00}{-1})^{\Large 30}\ \equiv\,\ 1})} = \bbox[5px,border:1px solid #c00]{4\,}}$

$\smash[t]{\text{The middle equality uses}\,\  \overbrace{ab\ \bmod ac\ =\,\ a\ (\,b\ \bmod\ c)}}\, =\,$  [$\!\bmod\!$ Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242), and we also used $\!\bmod 12\!:^{\phantom{|^{|^{|^|}}}}\!\!\!\! \color{#0a0}{26\equiv 2}\Rightarrow\, \color{#0a0}{26}^{N}\!\equiv \color{#0a0}2^N\,$ by the [Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242); similarly for $\,\color{#c00}{{2}^N}^{\phantom{|^{|^{|}}}}\!\!\!\!\!\equiv (\color{#c00}{-1})^N\!\pmod{\!3}$

---

**Or** $\ \color{#c00}{4^{\large n}\equiv 4}\pmod{\!12},\,$ since it is true $\!\bmod 3$ & $4\!:$   $\,1^{\large n}\!\equiv 1\,$ & $\,0^{\large n}\!\equiv 0,\,$ and $\,(3,4)=1$

So $\bmod 12\!:\ 26^{\large  32}\!\equiv 2^{\large 32}\!\equiv \color{#c00}{4^{\large 16}\!\equiv 4}.\ $  This is the idea behind Sam's answer.

**Remark**  $ $ Numbers like $4$ above with $a^2=a$ are called *idempotents*. This implies $\,a^{\large n} = a\,$ for all $n\ge 2$ either as above or by a simple induction $\,a^{\large n+1}\! = a\,a^{\large n} = a\cdot a = a.\,$ Said more conceptually: note $a$ is a fixed point of $\,f(x) = ax\,$ i.e. $\,f(a) = a,\,$ and fixed points always stay fixed on iteration by a simple induction: if $\,\color{#c00}{f^n(a) = a}\,$ then  $\,f^{\large n+1}(a) = f(\color{#c00}{f^{\large n}(a)}) = f(\color{#c00}a) = a$.

The $\!\bmod\!$ Distributive Law allows us to do this induction purely *arithmetically*, by cancelling out a factor to reduce it to the *trivial* induction $\,\color{#c00}1^n\equiv 1.\,$ Let's examine closely how it performs this.

Generally if $\,a^2\equiv a\pmod{\!n}\,$ then $\,n\mid a(a\!-\!1)\,$ [thus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/611202/242) $\, n = cm,\ c\mid a,\ \color{#c00}{m\mid a\!-\!1},\,$ hence

$$ a^{1+n}\bmod cm = c\overbrace{((a/c) a^n\bmod m)}^{\textstyle \color{#c00}{a}^n\equiv\color{#c00}1^n\!\pmod{\!m}} = c(a/c) = a\qquad$$

therefore $\bmod n\!:\,\ a^2\equiv a\,\Rightarrow\, a^{1+n}\equiv a,\,$ proved using only the *trivial* induction $\,\color{#c00}1^n\equiv 1$

**Or** $\ \color{#c00}{a^{\large n}\equiv a}\pmod{\!(a\!-\!1)a},\,$ since it is true mod $\,a\!-\!1\,$ & $\,a\!:$   $\,1^{\large n}\!\equiv 1\,$ & $\,0^{\large n}\!\equiv 0,\,$  so it's also true $\!\bmod {\rm lcm}(a\!-\!1,a) = (a\!-\!1)a\,$ by [CCRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2006919/242), so the congruence [persists](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/883060/242) $\!\bmod n\!=\!ac\mid (a\!-\!1)a$

Or using the Factor Theorem: $\,c\mid a,\ m\mid a\!-\!1\mid a^{n-1}\!-1\,\Rightarrow\, n=cm\mid a(a^{n-1}\!-1)$

It is instructive to examine the relationship between the various methods.

Idempotents $\!\bmod n$ play a fundament role in factorization of integers ([and rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3509367/242)) since they correspond to splittings of $n$ into coprime factors, cf.  [last paragraph here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/614256/242). However our first method using the mod Distributive Law is more general since the base is generally not idempotent  in such exponentiation problems (in fact the $\!\bmod\!$ Distributive Law is essentially an *operational* form of CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem - which yields a general way of solving this and related problems).

Answer (score 2):

Like

[Get the last two digits of $16^{100}$ and $17^{100}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607829/get-the-last-two-digits-of-16100-and-17100)

[How to find last two digits of $2^{2016}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844558/how-to-find-last-two-digits-of-22016)

[last two digits of $14^{5532}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1385396/last-two-digits-of-145532)

[Find the last two digits of $2^{2156789}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1804639/find-the-last-two-digits-of-22156789)

$$26\equiv-1\pmod3$$

$\implies26^{2n}\equiv(-1)^{2n}\equiv1\pmod3$ where $n$ is any integer

$\implies26^{2n+2}\equiv1\cdot26^2\pmod{3\cdot26^2}$

$\implies26^{2n+2}\equiv26^2\pmod{3\cdot2^2}\equiv?$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $26\equiv 2\pmod{12}$, so we can as well compute $r=2^{32}\bmod 12$.

We have $2^{32}=12q+r$, so clearly $r=4s$, so we are reduced to compute $2^{30}\bmod 3$ and now we can apply Fermat’s little theorem: $2^2\equiv 1\pmod 3$; thus $2^{30}\equiv 1=s\pmod{3}$ and therefore $r=4$.

Comment: Readers may be interested to know that this factoring out of $4$ can be done efficiently *operationally* using the mod distributive law (an *operational* reformulation of CRT) - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $26^{32}$ is clearly divisible by $4$ but not by $3$, so the possible congruence classes modulo $12$ are immediately only (represented by) $4$ and $8$. We have $4\equiv 1 \bmod 3$ and $8\equiv 2 \equiv -1 \bmod 3$, so to distinguish between them we only need to know the answer modulo $3$.

This comes down to $(-1)^{32}=1$ (or we can use little Fermat to the same effect) and the answer is therefore $4$.

Comment: Splitting the $12$ into the coprime factors $4$ and $3$ is a technique which is substantially generalised in the Chinese Remainder Theorem. The observations in this case are elementary and don't need complex machinery, but it is there if needed to steer the analysis of more complex cases.

Comment: This implicit factoring out of 4 can be explicitly achieved *operationally* using the mod distributive law (an operational reformulation of CRT) - see my answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque A useful and interesting perspective as usual!