# What are the possible value of the last digit of $6^n$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Question:

> What are the possible value of the last digit of $6^n?$

I know it has to do with Euler's theorem and we have to find the number modulus 10, but I can't get any further.

Comment: It's always 6. Just multiply and see.

Comment: You can also prove it using mathematical induction i.e. show that $6^n \equiv 6$ (mod 10)

Comment: Have you thought about what happens when you take a number ending in 6 and multiply it by 6?

Answer (score 2):

In $\mathbb{Z}/{10\mathbb{Z}}$ we have that $6^2 = 6$, so it's an idempotent.

It follows that all powers of $6$ (except the $0$-th power) are $6$, so all integers that have remainder $6$ when divided by $10$ (so last digit is $6$) stay that way in all their powers.

Comment: For more on such *idempotent fixed points* and the fundamental role they play in factorization see the [Remark here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2973731/242)

Answer (score 1):

You have

- $6^n \equiv_2 0$
- $6^n \equiv_5 1^n \equiv_5 1$

$$x \equiv_2 0, x \equiv_5 1 \Rightarrow \boxed{x\equiv_{10} 6}$$

Comment: Correct answer but which concrete rules did you apply here?

Comment: $10 = 2\cdot 5$. So, calculate with respect to the modules $2$ and $5$. The Chinese remainder theorem ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem ) gives then the answer wrt. the module $10$.

Comment: So you solved x=0 mod 2 and x=1 mod 5. With solution x=6 mod 10. Got it. Thanks

Comment: Exactly. You are welcome.

Comment: @niloderoock $\large \bmod 10\!:\ \,6^{\large 1+N} \equiv 6(\underbrace{6^{\large N} \bmod 5}_{\Large  1^{\large N}\ \equiv\ 1 })\equiv 6(1)\ $ by the [mod Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242), is a simple way to do it without CRT

Comment: One can also simply reason that even numbers which give a remainder of $1$ when divided by $5$ are those of the form $6+10\cdot k$. :-)

Comment: @trancelocation But that's essentially the same as applying CRT (unless one uses some ad hoc method such as brute-force search - which won't scale well to large numbers).  The mod Distributive Law is actually equivalent to CRT, but being *operational* it is often more convenient to apply in computations.