# Calculate $2^{5104} \bmod 10$ using mental arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, mental-arithmetic

I am practising interview for Jane Street's trader internship and I found the following question.

> Question: Calculate $2^{5104} \bmod  10$ using mental arithmetic.

I know that $2^5 \bmod 10 \equiv 2 \bmod 10.$
So, 
\begin{align*}
2^{5104} & = (2^5)^{1020} 2^4 \\
& \equiv 2^{1020}2^4 \\
& = (2^5)^{204}2^4 \\
& \equiv(2^5)^{40}2^8 \\
& \equiv (2^5)^8 2^8 \\
& \equiv (2^5)^3 2 \\
& \equiv 6 \bmod 10.
\end{align*}

However, I find the calculations above very taxing if I use mental arithmetic. I believe there should be a faster way to answer the question but I am not able to find one.

Comment: Mental arithmetic depends on practice and what facts you have available.  I find your approach a good one and with practice you can keep it in your head.  A more useful fact is that the cycle of $2^k \pmod m$ divides $\phi(m)$.  As $\phi(10)=4$ the cycle of $2^k \pmod {10}$ repeats with period $4$ (and maybe $2$ or $1$).  Then $2^{5104} \equiv 2^4 \equiv 6 \pmod {10}$.

Comment: $4\mid100$, so $4\mid5100$, so $4\mid5104$

Comment: I added an answer highlighting a *general* rule for problems like this. There are [over $74$ worked examples here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/2059752?sort=votes)

Comment: @Bill Dubuque Nice. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand)

Answer (score 5):

The cycle of units digits goes $2,\ 4,\ 8,\ 6,\ 2,...$, in a cycle of length 4 after the initial term of 1. $5104\equiv 4\pmod 4$, so the answer is the fourth term in the cycle which is $6$.

Comment: @Idonknow Sheesh, I managed to talk myself out of the correct explanation back there.  It is mod 4.

Comment: Haha you are right. May I know whether there is a theorem to justify your solution?

Comment: @Idonknow It's just calculating $2^{5104}\bmod 5$ knowing that $2^4\equiv 1\pmod 5$.  Then to figure it out mod 10 you just need to realize that 6 is the unit's place that is both even and equivalent to 1 modulo 5.

Comment: @Idonknow Again, **beware** that to be rigorous we need to either perform an *explicit* induction to prove how the pattern holds for all naturals (or else use some related result that does so). See my [comments on farruhota's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3492787/calculate-25104-bmod-10-using-mental-arithmetic/3493676#comment7185638_3493052) for elaboration.

Answer (score 4):

The *Chinese Remainder Theorem* says:
$$2^{5104}\equiv x \pmod{2\cdot 5} \iff \begin{cases}2^{5104}\equiv x\pmod 2 \\ 2^{5104}\equiv x\pmod 5\end{cases}$$
It follows that $x\equiv 0\pmod 2$ and $x\equiv 1\pmod 5$.

Consequently $x\equiv 6\pmod{10}$.

Comment: How did you get that $x \equiv 1 \pmod 5$?

Comment: @Zaz, it's Fermat's small theorem: $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$ for prime $p$ and relative prime $a$. So $2^4\equiv 1\pmod 5$ and $2^{5104}$ is a power of that.

Answer (score 3):

$$2^{5104}\equiv 16^{1276}\pmod{10}$$
$$\equiv 6\pmod {10}$$

Comment: Can you elaborate how to obtain second equivalence?

Comment: Every power of a number ending in $6$ ends with $6$.

Comment: I see. But I think that only applies to this particular case. More precisely, it applies when the power is divisible by $4.$

Comment: Yeah, @Idonknow.

Comment: @Idonknow $\ \bmod 10\!:\,\ 6^{\large 1+N} = 2(3\cdot 6^{\large N}\!\bmod 5) = 2(3) = 6\ $ as in my answer. See the [Remark here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2973731/242) for much further discussion on how this is related to alternative proofs (by induction, or by CRT or the Factor Theorem) for this  **power law for idempotents**.

Answer (score 3):

$$2^{4n+2}=(5-1)^{2n+1}=-(1-5)^{2n+1}$$

$$\equiv-1\pmod5\equiv4$$

$$\implies2^{4n+4}\equiv4\cdot2^2\pmod{5\cdot2^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

if a number is not divisible by five, its fourth power is equivalent to $1 \pmod 5$

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your suggestion work on my question?

Answer (score 2):

This is the same as determining the units digit of $2^{5104}$. The units digit of the powers of $2$ repeat in the sequence $2,4,8,6$ (i.e. the $(4k+i)$th power of $2$, where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $1\leq i\leq 4$, is the $i$th term in the sequence). Since $5104$ is a multiple of $4$, the answer is $6$.

Comment: Can you justify your last sentence? Why would $5104$ a multiple of $4$ gives the answer $6?$

Comment: $5104$ is also a multiple of $2$. Why isn't it $4?$

Comment: Euler totient theorem.

Comment: or an equivalent you can divide out by gcd to get rid of some complexity.

Comment: @Idonknow **Beware** that to obtain a *complete, rigorous* proof we need to either perform an *explicit* induction to prove how the pattern holds for all naturals (or else use some related result that does so). See my [comments on farruhota's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3492787/calculate-25104-bmod-10-using-mental-arithmetic/3493676#comment7185638_3493052) for elaboration.

Answer (score 2):

What is the remainder when you divide the exponent by 4?

If it is $0$ then last digit will be $6$. When it is $1$ then last digit will be $2$. For $2$ as remainder, last digit will be $4$ and finally for $3$, last digit is going to be $8$.But all this does not work when the exponent is $0$. For that case, last digit is $1$. So in present case, as the exponent $5104$ is wholly divisible by $4$, the last digit will be $6$.

The divisibility of a number by $4$ is not difficult to check either.  You just need to check number formed by the last two digits of the given number. The remainder that we get by dividing this number by 4 will be same as the remainder we get in case of original number. For the present case the two digit number is $04$ which is wholly divisible by $4$. And hence the original number $5104$ is also wholly divisible by $4$.

Answer (score 2):

Mental arithmetic comes with practice. For $n>0$:
$$2^{n}\equiv 2,4,8,6 \pmod{10} \Rightarrow 2^{5104}\equiv 2^{4\cdot 1276}\equiv 6\pmod{10}\\
3^{n}\equiv 3,9,7,1 \pmod{10} \Rightarrow 3^{5104}\equiv 3^{4\cdot 1276}\equiv 1\pmod{10}\\ 4^{n}\equiv 4,6 \pmod{10} \Rightarrow 4^{5104}\equiv 4^{2\cdot 2502}\equiv 6\pmod{10}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \\
7^{n}\equiv 7,9,3,1 \pmod{10} \Rightarrow 7^{5104}\equiv 7^{4\cdot 1276}\equiv 1\pmod{10}\\
8^{n}\equiv 8,4,2,6 \pmod{10} \Rightarrow 8^{5104}\equiv 8^{4\cdot 1276}\equiv 6\pmod{10}\\
9^{n}\equiv 9,1 \pmod{10} \Rightarrow 9^{5104}\equiv 9^{2\cdot 2502}\equiv 1\pmod{10} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $$
Different examples:
$$2^{n}\equiv 2,4,8,6 \pmod{10} \Rightarrow 2^{5102}\equiv 2^{4\cdot 1275+2}\equiv 4\pmod{10}\\
9^{n}\equiv 9,1 \pmod{10} \Rightarrow 9^{5105}\equiv 9^{2\cdot 2502+1}\equiv 9\pmod{10}$$
Can you find: $2^{325} \bmod 10$? $13^{1234} \bmod 10$? Answer:

> $2^{n}\equiv 2,4,8,6 \pmod{10} \Rightarrow 2^{325}\equiv 2^{4\cdot 81+1}\equiv 2\pmod{10}\\13^n\equiv 3^{n}\equiv 3,9,7,1 \pmod{10} \Rightarrow 13^{1234}\equiv 3^{4\cdot 308+2}\equiv 9\pmod{10}$

Comment: I am able to calculate the questions given in your post easily now. Thanks. By the way, do you know of any source (book/website) that contains a lot of exercises on calculating $a^b \bmod c$? I need to practise more.

Comment: Here are [one](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Modular_arithmetic/Introduction) and [two](https://www.brainkart.com/article/Exercise-2-3--Modular-Arithmetic_39312/).

Comment: @Idonknow **Beware** that there are no *proofs* above. What is displayed are  *cyclic patterns* that could be used to compose proofs. But to obtain a complete rigorous proof you either need to *explicitly* perform the hinted induction or else use some other method that nicely encapsulates the induction, e.g. the Congruence Power Rule, or the mod Distributive Law (as in my answer, which reduces the induction to the *trivial* induction $\,1^n\equiv 1;\,$ see the [Remark here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2973731/242) for much more on that)

Comment: One could argue that one of the main goals of an (elementary) Number Theory course is to teach how to properly make such arithmetical inductions, e.g.to prove that for *all* primes $\,p,\,$ we have $p\mid ab\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid a\,$ or $\,p\mid b.\,$ Ancients saw patterns for small primes but did not know how to (inductively) extend that intuition to a rigorous proof that works for *all* primes. Not too infrequently such patterns can hold for very many small number then later fail, so rigorous inductive proofs are *essential* in order to obtain correct results.

Comment: See R. K Guy's [Strong Law of Small Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_Law_of_Small_Numbers) for many interesting examples of such empirical "inductions" that fail to hold true.

Answer (score 2):

Notice  $\,\ 2^{\large 4+4N}\!\bmod 10
\, =\, \color{#c00}2\overbrace{(2^{\large 3}  \color{#0a0}2^{\large\color{#0a0}4N}\bmod 5)}^{\textstyle \color{#0a0}{2^{\large 4}}\!\equiv 1\pmod{\!5}} = 2(3)$

by applying $\ \color{#c00}ab\bmod \color{#c00}ac\, =\, \color{#c00}a(b\bmod c) = $ [$\!\bmod\!$ Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242) to factor out $\,\color{#c00}{a=2}$