# How to compute the the last digit of $122^{122}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, matlab

I try to use
$$122^{122} = 2^{122} (\mod 10)$$

But I use MATLAB that $122^{122}=2  (\mod 10)$ and $2^{122}=4  (\mod 10)$. Why they are not the same? The screenshot is as follows:

[image]

Comment: There must be an error , the unit digit will be 4.

Comment: @SunainaPati But I use Matlab...` mod(122^122,10)=2`?

Comment: see this then https://planetcalc.com/8326/?expression=122%5E122&modulo=10&showDetails=0 , it might help .

Comment: Did you forget parentheses or something?

Comment: @ChrisCuster I just use mod(122^122,10) in MATLAB. But the result is 2.

Comment: @Hermi Could you include a screenshot on the question?

Comment: Could you try $(122)\text{^}{122},122\text{^}({122})$ and $(122)\text{^}{(122)}$?

Comment: @Adola Sure just edited it.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Yes, I tried mod(122^(122),10) but it is still 2 but not 4.

Comment: Easiest way is as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3493676/242), using the mod Distributive Law.

Comment: See [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81228/11619) for everything you need to know. Appalled that anyone who has spent more than a year on the site would not immediately think of this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I no longer have access to Matlab so I can't reproduce this error exactly on my end. A similar mistake is observed when I use [Octave online](https://octave-online.net):

```
octave:2> mod(122^122, 10)
ans = 0
```

You should use a function such as [powermod](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/powermod.html#d122e223876). The trick is we do not want to compute $122^{122}$ explicitly.

Notice that $122^{122}$ is a very large number and it is working in double precision float point that exceeds [flintmax](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flintmax.html). Above this value, double-precision format does not have integer precision, and not all integers can be represented exactly.

The answer is indeed $4$.

Here are the Python outcome:

```
>>> 122**122 % 10 # cool, it can be computed
4
>>> pow(122, 122, 10) # preferred.
4
```

Comment: Deep. But then, that's what this site is for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Chinese remainder theorem.  Since $2$ and $10$ aren't relatively prime, Euler isn't directly applicable.

$10=2\cdot5$, and $2^{122}\equiv0\bmod2$.  We get $\varphi (5)=4\implies2^{122}\equiv2^2\equiv4\bmod5$, and the answer is $4$.

Answer (score 1):

$122^{122} \equiv 2^{122} (\text{mod $10$})$

As, $2^5\equiv 2 (\text{mod $10$})$
$\implies 2^{120}\equiv 2^{24} \equiv 2^{4} (\text{mod $10$})$
$\implies 2^{122} \equiv 2^{6} \equiv 4 (\text{mod $10$})$

Answer (score 1):

Look at the general problem of find the last digit of $n^m$.

Take $n=10N+h$ where $0\le h\le9$ and $m=4M+k$ where $0\le k\le3$.

Power of digits have a period of $4$ modulo $10$ the following way:
$$1\to1\to1\to1\\2\to4\to8\to6\\3\to9\to7\to1\\4\to6\to4\to6\\5\to5\to5\to5\\6\to6\to6\to6\\7\to9\to3\to1\\8\to4\to2\to6\\9\to1\to9\to1$$

Example: $797^{723}=(10N+7)^{4\cdot180+3}\equiv7^3\pmod{10}=3\pmod{10}$.

Apply this to find the answer to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, $ 122^{122} mod 10 = 4$. They are the same.