# How to find the remainder, if you divide $10^{10^7}$ + $10^{10^6}$ + $10^{10^5}$ + $10^{10^4}$ by 7.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have been trying to find the remainder, if you divide $10^{10^7}$ + $10^{10^6}$ + $10^{10^5}$ + $10^{10^4}$ by 7.

Considering the divisibility criteria by 7, i first looked at the division of the powers of 10 by 7.

10 = 1*7+3   remainder of 3,  $10^2$ = 14*7+2 remainder of 2, $10^3$ = 142*7+6 reminder of -1, $10^4$ = has a reminder of 4,   $10^5$ = has a reminder of 5,   $10^6$ = has a reminder of 1,   $10^7$ = has a reminder of 3

Is it sufficient to say that the reminders are 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5?

Comment: In order to make MathJax commands effective, you must surround them with `$` signs.

Comment: @saulspatz like how?

Comment: `$10^{10^7}$` comes out as $10^{10^7}$  You have to use braces to disambiguate the exponents.  You also need braces when there is more than one character in the exponent.

Comment: @saulspatz thanks

Comment: By [modular order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) we can reduce the exponents mod $\phi(7) = 6,\ $ where $10^2\equiv 4^2\equiv 4\,\Rightarrow\, 10^k\equiv 4\,$ for all $\,k\ge 1$, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2973731/242) on such idempotents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $10^i\equiv 4$ modulo $6$ for any positive integer $i$, we have that $10^{10^7}+10^{10^6}+10^{10^5}+10^{10^4}\equiv 4*10^4 \equiv 4*4=16\equiv 2$ modulo $7$.

Comment: Thanks so much Pavel Kozlov. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

$$10\equiv3\pmod7$$

Now using [Why is $a^n - b^n$ divisible by $a-b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188657/why-is-an-bn-divisible-by-a-b) $$10^{n+1}-10=10(10^n-1)\equiv0\pmod{10(10-1)}$$  for $n\ge0$

$$10^{n+1}\equiv10\pmod{90}\implies10^{n+1}\equiv10\pmod6\equiv4$$

$$\implies10^{10^{n+1}}\equiv3^{10^{n+1}}\equiv3^4\pmod7\equiv4$$

Comment: Thanks for providing the alternative way of solving the question.