# The original question says : Prove that $19\mid(2^{(2^{(6n+2)})}+3)$ $\forall$ $n \in N_0.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I simplified the problem as writing it first as $2^{2^{6n+2}}+3\equiv 0(mod 19)$ finally ending till $2^{2^{6n+2}}\equiv 2^4(mod 19)$.I cannot figure out how to deal with the exponents with the same base on both sides of the congruence.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried to find the multiplicative order of $2$ in $pmod{19}$?

Comment: what is $x?$ And add your work to the question. not just in comments.

Comment: Hint: $\,2^{\large N}\!\equiv 2^{\large N\bmod\color{#c00}{18}}\!\pmod{\!19},\,$ and $\,2^{\large 6n}\!\equiv 1\pmod{\!9}\overset{\times\ 4}\Longrightarrow 4\cdot 2^{\large 6n}\equiv 4\pmod{\color{#c00}{\!\!18}}\ \ $

Comment: Or, *operationally* $\ 4\cdot 2^{6n}\bmod 18 = 2(2\cdot 2^{6n}\bmod 9) = 2(2\cdot 1^n) = 4\ $ via the [mod Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2973731/242)

Comment: You just need to show that $ 16 \mid 2^{2^{6n+2} }$. To that end, write it as $ (2^{2^{6n}})^4 $, and simply observe $ 2 \mid 2^{2^{6n}} $.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By Fermat's little theorem,

$2^{18}\equiv 1\pmod{19}$.

So $2^{18k+4}\equiv 2^4\equiv -3\pmod{19}$ for any integer $k$. You can check that $18$ is the multiplicative order of $2$ although actually we don't need it.

Now, we want to find the residue of $4^{3n+1}$ modulo $18$.

$4^{3n+1}\equiv 64^n\cdot 4\equiv 10^n\cdot 4\pmod{18}$

You can check regardless of whether $n$ is even or odd, $4^{3n+1}\equiv 4\pmod{18}$.

So $2^{4^{3n+1}}+3\equiv 2^{18k+4}+3\equiv 2^4+3\equiv 0\pmod{19}$.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. site policy [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).