# About the congruence $x^k \equiv x \pmod 2$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How can one prove that $x^k\equiv x\pmod2$ for any integer $x$ and any positive integer $k>1$.

Comment: Any integer $x$ is congruent to $0$ or $1\pmod 2.$  Can you take it from there?

Comment: In any ring $\,x^2 = x\Rightarrow x^n = x\,$ for all $n> 0.\,$ See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2973731/242) for a few proofs. Here $\,x^2\equiv x\,$ by $\,2\mid x(x-1)\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x$ is even then obviously $x^k - x$ is even. If $x$ is odd then $x^k$ is odd, so $x^k - x$ even. Thus $x^k = x \mod 2$