# Congruence with powers - a bit stuck

Tags: modular-arithmetic

disclaimer : I am new to Congruences

I have the Following Congruence, and I am a bit stuck when trying to solve it

$2^{2^{(6L+2)}} + 11 \equiv 8 (mod19)$

what i have done is the following:

$16^{2^{(6L)}} \equiv 16 (mod19)$

$16^{64^{(L)}} \equiv 16 (mod19)$

at this stage I am stuck, what can I do now ?

Comment: One needs to know the concept of the (multiplicative) order of an element in modular arithmetic: $16^k \equiv 1\pmod{19}$ if and only if $k$ is a multiple of the order of $16$ modulo $19$.

Comment: @GregMartin, can you please elaborate more. i really want to understand this

Comment: @GregMartin, i have read about multiplicative order and i saw that for 16 it is 9. because $16^9 \equiv 1 (mod19)$

Comment: $\bmod 18\!:\ 64\equiv 10,\,$ and $10^{2}\equiv 10\Rightarrow \color{#c00}{10^{L}\equiv 10}\,$ for all $\,L>0\,$ (cf. idempotents [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3904284/242) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2973731/242)), so $\,2^{2+6L}\! = 4\cdot 64^L\equiv 4(\color{#c00}{10^L})\equiv 4(\color{#c00}{10})\equiv \color{#0a0}4,\,$ both for $\,L>0,\,$ *and* $\,L= 0\,$ (by $2^{2+6\cdot 0} = 4)\ \ $

Comment: Thus for all $\,L\ge 0\,$ we have $\bmod 19\!:\ 2^{\large 2^{2+6L}}\!\!\equiv 2^{\large\color{#0a0}4}\equiv 16\,$ by little Fermat & [modular order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) $ \ \ $